# Error nullpointer al realizar Contains con C# y EF CORE

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

Por favor ayuda para solucionar este problema. Tengo una lista de enteros y quiero consultar los registros de una tabla cuyos ids esten dentro de la lista mencionada anteriormente.

Cuando llego a esta linea :

```
var datos = new List<int> {297, 300};
var totalReg = context.AgedetMaes.Where( tnov => datos.Contains(tnov.Id)).Count();
```

me sale un error  :

No mapping to a relational type can be found for the CLR type 'List'.

y esta es la clase que mapea la clase con la tabla de la bd.

```
[Table("agedet_maes")]
    public class AgedetMaes
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AgdActivi { get; set; }
        public string AgdCodigo { get; set; }
        public string AgdDescrip { get; set; }
        public string AgdContinua { get; set; }
        public string AgdAplaza { get; set; }
        public string AgdGasodomestico { get; set; }
        public string AgdPrograma { get; set; }
        public string AgdAsigna { get; set; }
        public string AgdGenerasia { get; set; }
        public string AgdGeneraventa { get; set; }
        public string AgdGeneraSia { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public string AgdEstado { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: ya he intentado lo mismo con un arreglo de enteros y da el mismo resultado.  El id en la tabla es entero.

Comment: si ejecutas `var list = context.AgedetMaes.ToList();` obtienes los registros sin error ?

Comment: si, sale bien, pero esa es una validacion inicial, luego debo incluirla dentro de otra consulta.

Comment: que version de `EF Core` estas usando ?